# Atomically renaming tables name in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a table T in Oracle DB and I need to load (replace) the data on this table.
Replacing the data can be a long process and there are other processes that can use this table during my loading process (other processes can be running or start  after I begin my loading process).

The solution is to load the data into a temporary table T_TMP and when the loading process will finish, we will:
 1. Rename table T to T_REMOVE.
 2. Rename table T_TMP to T.

During above renaming steps, other processes/jobs can use table T so they can receive invalid data.
Therefor, I need to rename the tables **atomically**.

In MySQL, the atomic statement is:

```
RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name
[, tbl_name2 TO new_tbl_name2] ...
```

The question is what is the parallel atomic statement in Oracle?

it was suggested to use transactions: `delete from t; insert into t ...; commit;`
But the loading process isn't a simple insert statements but a script that I should run:
`sqlldr user/pass control=scopes_group.ctl direct=true`.
The file "scopes_group.ctl":

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'scopes_group.dat' BADFILE 'scopes_group.bad' DISCARDFILE 'scopes_group.dsc' TRUNCATE INTO TABLE T FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS (group_id , scopes char(4000) "replace(:scopes,';',',')", updated SYSDATE)
```

Thank you!
Mike

Comment: [Take a wild guess](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9020.htm#SQLRF01608)

Comment: Are you sure your approach is the right one? Did you ever heard about "Transactions", i.e. `COMMIT` statement?

Comment: Not really. I am not familiar with Oracle very well.
I am looking for simple and SAFE solution here.

Comment: `delete from t; insert into t ...; commit;` no need to rename it.  Renaming it can't be done atomically in Oracle (and I doubt it's really atomically in MySQL given the fact that the system catalogs are still stored in MyISAM which does not support transactions or atomic statements)

Comment: Nice approach! what if there are other processes that currently using table T?  maybe I should combine and do: "insert into T_TMP; drop TABLE T; rename  TABLE T_TMP to T; commit". will it work?

Comment: The other processes (or more precise other sessions) will see the old data. It becomes visible to other sessions only after COMMIT;

Comment: Oracle still doesn't support transactional DDL. `drop table` will do an implicit commit. You can't do that inside a transaction (well you _can_ but it then defeats the purpose of the transaction)

Comment: So, if I use "delete from t; insert into t ...;" without the "commit", no change will be done in the DB till I'll use the "commit"?

Comment: yes, just after the "COMMIT;" statement oracle transaction will be ended and the user will be able to see new data on the tables.

Comment: It is a great solution but I don't sure transaction will support it:
The loading process isn't a simple insert statements but a script "sqlldr user/pass control=scopes_group.ctl direct=true".
The file "scopes_group.ctl":
` LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'scopes_group.dat'
    BADFILE 'scopes_group.bad'
    DISCARDFILE 'scopes_group.dsc'
    TRUNCATE
    INTO TABLE T
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    TRAILING NULLCOLS
  (group_id     ,
        scopes char(4000) "replace(:scopes,';',',')",
        updated SYSDATE)
`

Comment: So, `sqlldr` into `T_TMP`, then `DELETE FROM T; INSERT INTO T SELECT * FROM T_TMP; COMMIT;`.  Then cleanup `T_TMP`